# How to write session in MVC3 View(Razor)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

hi  friends  how can i get session value in mvc view.

i need to write like that

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Upload Images", "IndexBib", "Cataloging", new { Area = "Cataloging" },new {//session value for id parm//)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you could do it like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Upload Images", "IndexBib", "Cataloging", new { Area = "Cataloging", id = (string)Session["param"]}, null)
```

Comment: i have tried  your code but its creating id of anchor tag except  passing the parm id

Comment: sorry havnt worked that much with areas, but i edited my codesample, i think this would work if you have set-up you area.

Comment: sorry  it  was  my  mistake  i was not using null  in the end  ...now  its  working thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"].ToString()
```